# What is the throttling time between requests for Box API?

Tags: box-view-api

Can't find it anywhere on Box View site.  Just wondering how long I should wait between trying to convert documents.

Answer (score 3):

When you make a request that exceeds a rate limit, you'll receive an a response with an HTTP status of `429 TOO MANY REQUESTS`and the retry time will be included as a `Retry-After` header e.g.

```
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
Retry-After: {retry time in seconds}
```

You can use the `{retry time in seconds}` to determine how long to wait.

Docs: http://developers.box.com/view/#rate-limiting

Comment: I'd also recommend looking at the [webhooks documentation](http://developers.box.com/view/webhooks/). If you wait for the `document.done` (or `document.error`) webhook, you can be sure when to send another document without getting rate-limited.